# Update jqTree options after initialization?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have jqTree working in my project but I need to update the dragAndDrop option after jqTree initialization.

Is there a way to update options like in jQuery UI or do I have to "destroy" the plugin and initialize it again with the new options (in that case how do I destroy the plugin) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JqTree does not support the updating of options.

You can destroy the plugin like this:

`$('#tree1').tree('destroy');`